# text in front of multiple images

Tags: html, css

hi I'm assigned to do a basic profile page for class, but for one of the html pages I am unable to put the text in front of each individual image, i removed my attempts at it to help ease confusion.

```
<div class="aboutmeprofile">
    <h2 id="h2">Portfolio</h2>
    <hr></hr>
    <img src="assets/images/gym.jpg" alt="gym">Gym
    <img src="assets/images/hiking.jpg" alt="hiking">Hiking
    <img src="assets/images/overwatch.jpg" alt="overwatch">Overwatch
    <img src="assets/images/running.jpg" alt="running">Running
    <img src="assets/images/programming.jpg" alt="programming">Programming
</div>
```

```
  .aboutmeprofile {
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
    width: 650px;
    margin: 10px;
    line-height: 150%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear , do you want to overlap the text on image or below the image

Comment: sorry i wanted it similar to this website example, but i could not replicate https://css-tricks.com/examples/TypeOverImage/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to absolute position your text in front of the image with css. It helps to wrap each image and text item into a block to apply the css.

```
<div class="aboutmeprofile">
    <h2 id="h2">Portfolio</h2>
    <hr/>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="assets/images/gym.jpg" alt="gym">
        <span>Gym</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="assets/images/hiking.jpg" alt="hiking">
        <span>Hiking</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="assets/images/overwatch.jpg" alt="overwatch">
        <span>Overwatch</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="assets/images/running.jpg" alt="running">
        <span>Running</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="assets/images/programming.jpg" alt="programming">
        <span>Programming</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.item {
    position: relative;
}

.item span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

**Edit:** Added a simplified fiddle example

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.aboutmeprofile {
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 10px;
    line-height: 150%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.item {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.item span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="aboutmeprofile">
    <h2 id="h2">Portfolio</h2>
    <hr/>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/400x300/ddd/ddd" alt="gym">
        <span>Gym</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/400x300/ddd/ddd" alt="hiking">
        <span>Hiking</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/400x300/ddd/ddd" alt="overwatch">
        <span>Overwatch</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/400x300/ddd/ddd" alt="running">
        <span>Running</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/400x300/ddd/ddd" alt="programming">
        <span>Programming</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i attempted the first image only <div class="aboutmeprofile">
    <h2 id="h2">Portfolio</h2>
    <hr/>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="assets/images/gym.jpg" alt="gym">
        <span>Gym</span>
    </div>

using the same css, but the text is now to the very right of the image not overlayed

Comment: you'll have to add a `left` value for css to realign the text to the center of the image. I've updated my answer with a fiddle example.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to create a div for the label and use the image as the background-image for the div.

```
background-image: image.png
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rL8cchyr/1/)

Answer (score 0):

this is what I came up with. Just add the other images and its respective label:

```css
 #h2, #h3 {
 color: #4aaaa5;
 text-align: left;
 font-size: 30px;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: 'Georgia', Times, Times New Roman, serif;}

    #linebreak {
    clear: both;
     border: 1px solid gray;
     width: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;}
        .aboutmeprofile {
         float: left;
         background-color: white;
         width: 650px;
         margin: 10px;
         line-height: 150%;
         padding: 10px;
         margin-top: 30px;
        }

    .aboutmeprofile {
 float: left;
 background-color: white;
 width: 650px;
 margin: 10px;
 line-height: 150%;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-top: 30px;
}


  .container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.image {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="aboutmeprofile">
 <h2 id="h2">Portfolio</h2>
 <hr>
<div class="container">
  <img class="image" src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg" />
  <span class="text">
   Gym
  </span>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img class="image" src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg" />
  <span class="text">
    Hiking
  </span>
</div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I also used a stock photo, since I don't have the images. You can just change it back to your images.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this with `position:absolute` property , first you need to create a `relative` div , then call the `image` and `h2` inside the div , then set `absolute` position to `h2`

**Check with the snippet**

```css
.content_div {
 position:relative;
}
.content_div h2 {
 position:absolute;
 bottom:25px;
 color:#fff;
 font-size:18px;
}
.content_div h2 span {
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 padding:10px;
 display:block;
 border-bottom:2px solid #000;
}
.content_div h2 span:last-child{
 border-bottom:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="content_div">
 <img src="http://www.picgifs.com/graphics/c/cute/graphics-cute-160852.jpg" alt="image" />
    <h2>
    <span>A Movie in the Park:</span>
    <span>Kung Fu Panda</span>
    </h2>
</div><!-- /.content_div -->
```